# Unable to find a solution for a "java logical error" in Quadratic Equation program

Tags: java, math

Although the program works perfectly fine, my professor mentioned that the following is a logical error and should be fixed. I'm stumped, isn't there only one root when the discriminant is equal to 0? Help will truly be appreciated!

This is the code he mentioned:

```
     if(discrim == 0) 
     { 
         eq1root1 = ((-1*coefB) + Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2 * coefA);
         System.out.println("This equation only has a single real root. Root = " + eq1root1);
```

Here's the full code:

```
import java.lang.Math;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane; 

public class Assignment6
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String a, 
           b,
           c; 
  double coefA,
         coefB,
         coefC,
         discrim,
         eq1root1,
         eq1root2;

  //Here the user is inputting the coefficients through a popup dialog box
  //Then the entered Strings are being converted to floating point numbers.  

  a = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number for the quadratic coefficient a" ); 
  coefA = Double.parseDouble (a);        
  b = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number for the quadratic coefficient b" );
  coefB = Double.parseDouble (b);  
  c = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter a number for the quadratic coefficient c" );
  coefC = Double.parseDouble (c);  

   //Here the coefficients that the user entered are being displayed. 

   System.out.println("Your coefficient  a = " + coefA);
   System.out.println("Your coefficient  b = " + coefB);
   System.out.println("Your coefficient  c = " + coefC);

  //The following "nested if" statement sorts out equations with only 1 root, 2 roots, and or no roots at all.  
   discrim = coefB*coefB - (4 * coefA * coefC);
   if(discrim == 0) 
     { eq1root1 = ((-1*coefB) + Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2 * coefA);
      System.out.println("This equation only has a single real root. Root = " + eq1root1);
     }  
   else  if (discrim > 0)
   { eq1root1 = ((-1*coefB) + Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2 * coefA);
     eq1root2 =((-1*coefB) - Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2 * coefA);
     System.out.println("This equation has two real roots."); 
     System.out.println("Root 1 = " +  eq1root1); 
     System.out.println("Root 2 = " + eq1root2);
   }
   else 
   {
      System.out.println("This equation does not have any real roots."); 
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: This is an old comment, but just an fyi we're in the process of eliminating the homework tag. So if you see a question with the homework tag, please remove it! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only error I can see is that you don't really need to do:

```
 eq1root1 = ((-1*coefB) + Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2 * coefA);
```

You can do only

```
 eq1root1 = -1*coefB/(2 * coefA);
```

Since you're inside the if where you know the descriminant is zero.

Like mentioned in another comment, you need to make sure that coefA is different from 0, since that will cause your code to raise an exception (you can't divide by 0). Although that wouldn't *actually* be a quadratic equation, it's important to validate it.

Comment: Glad to be of help. :) If it *does* solve your problem, please consider accepting the answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Think about this equation in terms of math:

```
((-1*coefB) + Math.sqrt(discrim))/(2 * coefA);
```

What happens when `coefA = 0` ?

Comment: Right side becomes undefined :-)

Comment: For pure math, that or infinity.  But IIRC Java will throw an exception.  Either way, it's a special case that you need extra logic to handle.  Print out some sort of error message - for example, "This isn't a quadratic equation".  I've marked students off for this type of bug before.

Answer (score 2):

I can only guess here... What professor was *probably* trying to say is that you cannot really use `==` to compare `double`s.

For example,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double v = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        v += 0.01;
    final double w = 1;
    System.out.println("v = " + v);
    System.out.println("w = " + w);
    if (v - w != 0.0) {
        System.out.println("difference: " + (v - w));
    }
}
```

will print the following:

```
v = 1.0000000000000007
w = 1.0
difference: 6.661338147750939E-16
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider what happens if doubles don't accurately represent numbers properly:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Assignment6
Your coefficient  a = 1.0
Your coefficient  b = 0.2
Your coefficient  c = 0.01
This equation has two real roots.
Root 1 = -0.09999999868291098
Root 2 = -0.10000000131708903
```

I constructed this example with `(x + .1)^2` which should have 1 solution. The expansion is `x^2 + .2x + .01`.

You also aren't handling when `a = 0`

```
C:\Documents and Settings\glowcoder\My Documents>java Assignment6
Your coefficient  a = 0.0
Your coefficient  b = 1.0
Your coefficient  c = 1.0
This equation has two real roots.
Root 1 = NaN
Root 2 = -Infinity
```